Capitalized "Kagome" or lowercase "kagome"?
I am a non-native English speaker. If I am referring to a Kagome lattice, should I capitalize the leading 'k'?
I find the usage of both upper and lower cases is abundant on the Internet.

The 'kagome' is a traditional woven bamboo pattern, whereas 'Kagome' is the name of a children's game or a food company.

What would be the proper use if someone is trying to use it as the name of a lattice (in physics context)?

Wikipedia tries to reflect the more common usage, and the article you link has a lower-case "k", as do most (but not all) of its references.

A kagome – woven pattern – lattice. It doesn't seem to be a proper name: your Wikipedia link says "The term kagome lattice was coined by Japanese physicist Kôdi Husimi".

The general rule is that you capitalize phrases like this if it's named after something that would be a proper noun you keep the capitalization, e.g. Bose-Einstein condensate or Klein bottle. If it's not named after a person or place, it's lowercase.

The word "kagome" is a borrowing from Japanese.  It is not a person's name, nor the name of a place.  It is a simple common noun, and so is not capitalised, unless it appears at the start of a sentence or in a title.
Foreign words are not capitalised in English, even if they would be in their native language. So we write "sushi" and "fuhrer" even though in their native languages they would be written 寿司 and Führer. Proper nouns are capitalised, even if they would not be in their native language, so write "Tokyo" and "Saanich" even though they would be written 東京, and W̱SÁNEĆ in their native languages.  There is some variation, some people will include the umlaut ü or other diacritics even when writing English.

Thank you, James.
